# Boostrap's modal dialog always displays on refresh even with show set to false

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and am having a few issues getting modal dialogs to work correctly. Despite setting show:false, the dialog displays every time the page is refreshed.

Here’s a fiddle showing the issue: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rboarman/kn8wh/3/)

Code:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#modalwrapper" >Log On</a>


<div class="modal" id="modalwrapper">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h2>Log On</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body span7">    
      Body
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>


$(function () {
    $('#modalwrapper').modal({
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        show: false
    });
});
```

I have verified that the .modal call is being executed.

What am I doing wrong? Adding a display:none style addresses the issue but that is not the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the modal using the provided `hide` bootstrap class

```
<div class="modal hide" id="modalwrapper">
  ..
</div>
```

which (by looking on `bootstrap.css`) is basically what you imagined

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Alexander answered, add a `.hide` class to your model's `div`. In fact, that's exactly how the documentation's demo is set up. From the source of http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals:

```
      <!-- sample modal content -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</a>
          <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
          <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem.</p>

          <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
          <p>This <a href="#" class="btn popover-test" title="A Title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">button</a> should trigger a popover on hover.</p>

          <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
          <p><a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">This link</a> and <a href="#" class="tooltip-test" title="Tooltip">that link</a> should have tooltips on hover.</p>

          <hr>

          <h4>Overflowing text to show optional scrollbar</h4>
          <p>We set a fixed <code>max-height</code> on the <code>.modal-body</code>. Watch it overflow with all this extra lorem ipsum text we've included.</p>
          <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
          <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
          <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
          <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>
```

A lot of the time you'll want to check out the source of Bootstrap's documentation to fully understand a feature (for example, the only way to know how to use `.form-actions` is to view the source of the demo; it's not explicitly documented).